# JSF Javascript calls Primefaces componants

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

hi i want to make a call to back bean periodically from java script function i want to refresh a panel of my page instead of whole page
this is what i have written in script

`$('#submitbutton').click();`

```
<h:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" 
                            action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}" >
```

and instead of refreshing i want to refresh a panel only of the page

```
<p:panel id="dailyGraphPanel">
                    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
                </p:panel>
```

so how can i do that thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Primeface Poll tag

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="Submit" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}">
    <f:ajax render="dailyGraphPanel" execute="@this"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Or

```
<p:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="Submit" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}" update="dailyGraphPanel" process="@this" />

<h:panelGroup id="dailyGraphPanel">
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: hi ashok thanks for reply i tried it but it showing blank panel i have a script through which i am plotting a graph

Comment: As per your question "make a call to back bean periodically" - "refresh a panel". Poll tag will work perfectly. JS no need here.

Comment: but i am making that call from javascript $('#submitbutton').click();

Comment: [Remote Command](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml). Hope it ll useful

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise you to use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

It would be, IMHO, much simplier and cleaner to group your chart component #chartdiv refresh with your panel refresh.

However, a quick solution with few modifications and maybe fitting constraints you do not explain there could be for you to switch from

```
<h:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}" >
```

to

```
<p:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}" update="dailyGraphPanel">
```

Depending on the relative positions of your p:commandButton and p:panel, pour might have to adjust the path of the component to update, or maybe just use one of those handy primefaces functions, p:component

```
<p:commandButton id="submitbutton" immediate="true" value="" styleClass="ui-day" style="border:0;display : none;" action="#{liveGraphBean.plotInterval1('daily')}" update="#{p:component}">
```

I do not see the update attribute in h:commandButton doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ but you will find it in p:commandButton http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/commandButton.html

You should read the "Partial Rendering" section in PrimeFaces doc for a more detailed explanation on how this works (section 4.1, page 498 of PrimeFaces excellent user guide http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf ).

Comment: hi Ludoic thanks for reply i tried it but my whole page is getting refreshed